# Why dll-imported C/C++ functions without parameters do not work in a VB app, while the ones with parameters do?

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net, dll, import

I'm developing an application in **VB** which requires importing functions from a **C/C++ DLL**.

The DLL is a black-box API, so I can only access signatures.
The function which is not working is structured like this:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus  // Prevent C++ name mangling to assure portability
extern "C" {
#endif

  // Add optional prefix to function prototypes based on defines.
#ifdef DLL_IMPORT
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#ifdef DLL_EXPORT
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API
#endif
#endif

API enum_struct_t functionName(void);

typedef enum enum_struct
{
 success = 0,
 failure = 1,
 other = 2
} enum_struct_t
```

The other functions are exactly the same, with the same return type, but they have parameters.
Now, I imported several of the functions structuring them like this:

```vb
Declare Auto Function functionName_i Lib "library.dll" Alias functionName(ByVal 
something, ByRef somethingElse) As ReturnEnum

Public Function functionName(ByVal something, ByRef somethingElse) As ReturnEnum
    Return (functionName_i (something, somethingElse))
End Function

Public Enum ReturnEnum
  Success = 0
  Failure = 1
  Other = 2
End Enum
```

When the functions I import have parameters, either by ref or value, everything works all right.
But when I try to use a function without parameters, **like functionName(void) above**, it does not work, **with an exception telling me it was impossible to call the function from the library.**

**Where is my mistake? How should I import functions without parameters correctly?**

Of course, the function without parameters is imported like this:

```
Declare Auto Function noParamFunction_i Lib "library.dll" Alias noParamFunction() 
As ReturnClass

Public Function noParamFunction() As ReturnClass
   Return (noParamFunction_i())
End Function
```

Thanks,
hope you can help me!

Comment: Could it be the return type that is wrong? In addition, using an explicit "void" when there are no parameters is non-standard in c++.Try declaring the function as int functionName() {}

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: The return type is the same for all functions, and with the ones that have parameters gives me no problems. Also, I cannot edit the DLL functions, as they are from proprietary tech. I'm not allowed to touch those. I'll provide a minimal reproducible example as soon as I can

Comment: What's `API`? Now please, do show a [mcve]. Make sure that it's *minimal* and *complete*.

Comment: @IInspectable sorry but this is everything I have. As I told you, I can only reference the signatures of the dll, but I do not know nothing of the code inside, as I cannot see it nor access it. This is everything I have. I would like to know if that void should be replaced with something else in VB, even if it means no parameters.

Comment: That's not everything you got. Surely `API` evaluates to *something* for the declarations to make any sense.

Comment: What is `ReturnClass`?  You show the C++ side of what is returned, but not the VB side.

Comment: Added the ReturnClass definition, changed to an Enum as it is an Enum. But it really does not matter: every function has that structure as return type, and every function that has parameters works.

The thing is: why functions without parameters won't work?

Comment: In the Declare statement try putting the alias in quotes "noParamFunction" and add space between alias and empty parenthesis ()